# How to make a submitted form undergo approval before appearing on the index page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, admin, ejs

Hi i'm building a app for people to be able to post jobs on a job board. But currently if a job is posted it goes straight to the homepage/index page and i don't want that. I want to be able to review the job posting before it goes live on the job board/homepage/index page. Any tutorial on this?

I.m currently using previous tutorial on Node to build this project.

```js
// Example code, but similar to actual code

//models config
let jobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    category: String,
    description: String,
    type: String,
    url: String,
    email: String,
    apply: String,
    location: String,
    company: String,
    path: String,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

let Job = mongoose.model('job', jobSchema);
// {type: String, default: "placeholdeimage.jpg"}

//routes config

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/uploads/');
    },

    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var originalname = file.originalname;
        var extension = originalname.split(".");
        filename = Date.now() + '.' + extension[extension.length-1];
        cb(null, filename);
    }
});


app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.redirect('/jobs')
})

app.get('/jobs',  (req, res) =>{
    Job.find({}).sort({ date: -1}).find(function(err, jobs){
        if(err){
            console.log('error')
        }

        return res.render('index', {jobs: jobs})

    })

})

//add form route
app.get('/jobs/add', (req, res) => {
    res.render('add')
})

app.post('/jobs', multer({storage: storage, dest: 
'./public/uploads/'}).single('file'), (req, res) => {

    req.body.description = req.sanitize(req.body.description);

    Job.create( (err, addJob) =>{

        if(req.file){
            let fullPath = "uploads/"+req.file.filename;
            let document = {
                title: req.body.title,
                category: req.body.category,
                description: req.body.description,
                type: req.body.type,
                url: req.body.url,
                email: req.body.email,
                apply: req.body.apply,
                location: req.body.location,
                company: req.body.company,
                path: fullPath
            };

            let job = new Job(document); 
                job.save()
        }else{
            console.log('file not uploaded')
            logo = 'noimage.jpg'
        }

        //redirect to index page
        return res.redirect('/jobs')
    })
})

app.get('/jobs/:id', (req, res) => {
    Job.findById(req.params.id, (err, jobDetails) => {
        if(err){
            res.redirect('/jobs')
        }else{
            res.render('details', {job: jobDetails});
        }
    })
})


app.listen(port, process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, ()=> console.log(`Server 
is running on ${port}`))
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <% for (const job of jobs) { %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column logo" style="width:10%;">
        <img src='<%= job.path %>'>
      </div>
      <div class="column title">
        <h2>
          <%=job.title%>
        </h2>
        <p>
          <%=job.company%>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="column type">
        <h2>
          <%=job.type%>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="column location">
        <h2>
          <%=job.location%>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h2><a href="/jobs/<%= job._id %>"><button>Apply</button></a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  <% } %>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a field `approved: { type: Boolean, default: false }` to `JobSchema` and retrieve the jobs with a condition.

```
Job.find({approved:true}).sort({ date: -1})...
```

Comment: It's working, thanks. But how come when i set the schema to `approved: { type: Boolean, default: false }` and `Job.find({approved:true}).sort({ date: -1})...` nothing shows but when i switch it to `Job.find({approved:false}).sort({ date: -1})...` the content appears? thought changing it `true` is supose to make it appear and not the other way around.

Comment: By default `approved` will be false that's why nothing shows. You can create a page for admin where you should retrieve all `approved:false` jobs and  make it `approved:true` using checkbox or something. I hope you understood.